# StructureMap GetInstance pass params

Tags: .net-core, structuremap

How to pass string connectionString, ILogger logger into Application class with StructureMap

I can create

```
_application = container.GetInstance<Application>();
```

but I can not pass params

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionString = "...";
    ILogger logger = xxxx;

    var container = Container.For<ConsoleRegistry>();
    _application = container.GetInstance<Application>();
    _application.Start(appSettings.RunCandleFetch);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class ConsoleRegistry : Registry
{
    public ConsoleRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
}

private class Application
{
    public Application(string connectionString, ILogger logger)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where were you planning on getting the connection string from?

Comment: In Main method I am reading this

Answer (score 2):

This documentation page should be very helpful: http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime/

This should work for you:

```cs
var args = new ExplicitArguments();
args.SetArg("connectionString", connectionString);
args.SetArg("logger", logger);

var app = container
    .GetInstance<Application>(args);
```